# How to bind RecyclerView image using Glide from data class

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-glide

I am trying to bind recycler view with databinding class that is working perfectly with following code

```
@BindingAdapter("retailPrice")
fun TextView.setRetailPrice(item: VegetableDailyPriceCalender?){
    item?.let {
        text = item.retailPrice.toString()
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("ourPrice")
fun TextView.setOurPrice(item: VegetableDailyPriceCalender?){
    item?.let {
        text = item.ourPrice.toString()
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("itemName")
fun TextView.setItemName(item: VegetableDailyPriceCalender?){
item?.let {
    text = item.vegetable.name
    text
}
}

@BindingAdapter("itemImage")
fun ImageView.setSleepImage(item: VegetableDailyPriceCalender?) {
item?.let {
    setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
}
}
```

Now I want to convert last binding to load dynamic image from internet using Glide library **Glide need code like below**

```
fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String?){
    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = it.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        Glide.with(imgView.context)
            .load(imgUri)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image))
            .into(imgView)
    }
}
```

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

UPDATE...
I tried following way but confused what to pass into **with()** and **into()**

```
fun ImageView.setSleepImage(item: VegetableDailyPriceCalender?) {
    val imgUri = item.vegetable.photoUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
    item?.let {
        setImageResource(Glide.with(imgView.context)
            .load(imgUri)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image))
            .into(imgView))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create BindingAdapter like below:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun setImageUrl(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String?){

    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = it.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        Glide.with(imgView.context)
            .load(imgUri)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image))
            .into(imgView)
    }
}
```

And use like below:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    imageUrl="@{viewModel.imageUrl}"/>
```

You can also use extension function like your's one

```
@BindingAdapter("itemImage")
fun ImageView.setSleepImage(item: VegetableDailyPriceCalender?) {
    val imgUri = item.vegetable.photoUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
    item?.let {
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(imgUri)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image))
            .into(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have dataclass as binding reference so should i fetch url and then pass it to param

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: I have updated my solution with your updated code. Check last one please

Comment: Thank you very much it is working perfectly. One more last question which one best way for binding first one or second one.

Comment: You can go with either one, the impact is same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205596/discussion-between-vikas-roy-and-md-asaduzzaman).

Answer (score 2):

XML ImageView would be like this : ,

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageId"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:src="LOADING_PHOTO_HERE"
     bind:imageUrl="@{`https://YOUR_IMAGE_URL`}"
     android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     tools:ignore="contentDescription" />
```

Code Part:

```
@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url) {
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.LOADING_PIC)
                .into(view);
    }
```

Comment: Hello thank you, but is there a way by passing data class a param to binding adapter.